# Rapid stack allocations vs accessing a single heap allocation

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, compiler-optimization, stackalloc

I'm having a situation where I have an array `T[]` which must be copied in an instant and sent over to a function accepting a `ReadOnlySpan<T>`. I found two solutions on this problem. However I'm interested in the one which gives the better performance.

Considerations:

- Array number of elements range between 1 to 3 (so it's extremely small);
- T is a `readonly struct` of 16 bytes managed size

1. I create another array `T[]` globally (which will be heap allocated) and then use the `.CopyTo()` extension method on the first array and then pass down the second array
2. I create a `Span<T>` locally using `stackalloc` (which will be stack allocated) and then use `.CopyTo<T>()` extension just like the previous version.

The difference is that the second approach requires me to do this every time the function is called, whereas the first approach the array is already initialized before the function is called even the first time.

Which approach do you guys think it's the better one ?

Comment: Don't ask us; install [benchmark dot net](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html) and race a billion horses

Comment: If you only need a `ReadOnlySpan<T>` you shouldn't need to copy anything?

Comment: If I don't copy it's going to be passed by reference (despite the fact the ReadOnlySpan<T> is a struct it is backed by an array which is a reference). This was actually a bug I had to fix so I've already tried that

Comment: Yes, the span will refer to the original memory, that is the whole point of spans. If the array is never written to for the duration of the call it should not matter if you have a copy or not. If it *is* written to you may have a race-condition or other threading issues that needs to be addressed, and you need to be very careful that you are not just making the bug more difficult to reproduce.

Comment: when I said copy I meant copy onto another array (and it did work) because only the original array was being changed. But nonetheless I will answer my own question with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I ran some benchmark dotnet tests. The results were almost 99% the same (taking about speed) with a small in favor of the `stackalloc` version, but only if I had used in combination with the `[SkipLocalsInit]` attribute. Also total allocations were higher for this version. So to summarize I came to the conclusion that this is just a micro-optimization and both variants are fine as long as you keep an eye on the stack size, otherwise first version is 10x better.

And not in the end, if you thought `ReadOnlySpan<T>` is always pass by value, think again when looking at my example